# What are the chances of finding a small factor?

Tags: nt.number-theory, factorization

**EDIT 2011.05.09**
Thanks to Junkie and Tapio Rajala for checking on me.  While most of the candidates
referred to below have small factors, the "large" small factors I list below are incorrect.  Also, that $2^{2557} - 2^{1278} + 1$ does not have a small factor supports my "feeling" that the candidate set should have not so many small factors as I was seeming to find.  I apologize for submitting such false suggestions to MathOverflow.  (This post will teach me to double check my work before posting, cautious language notwithstandng.)  Further updates (if any) will be near the end of this post.
**END EDIT 2011.05.09**

Following this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62797/even-perfect-numbers-n-with-n1-prime/62896#62896)
to a question of Luis Gallardo, I set my computer to look for small factors.  After looking through a lot of primes, my computer suggests that $223381441$ divides $2^{2557} - 2^{1278} + 1$ and that $234355951$ divides $2^{121} - 2^{60} + 1$.  The remaining exponent to be cracked is $132049$ (find a nontrivial factor or establish primality of $2^{264097} -  2^{132048} + 1$).  Given that the initial candidate set was based on the $47$ known perfect numbers and that the largest of the smallest factors of all but one of them is $2^{37} - 2^{18} + 1$ (meaning that the perfect number with Mersenne exponent $19$ precedes a prime), how can I use this information to determine how likely it is that the remaining candidate has a small ($< 2^{32}$) prime factor?

(If you have a bignum package and want to do a few primality tests, I would receive that information. I would also appreciate independent verification that $42$ of the $47$ candidates are composite with small prime factors.  Currently I am using 32-bit arithmetic and the moral equivalent of trial factorization to determine primality of these candidates.  In spite of my initial observations that $7$ or $11$ divide most of the candidates, I am surprised at my success so far in finding small prime factors.  Or should I be?  That is the point of this question.)

(Also, to answer Luis's question, at this point I'd say about four or five.)

**EDIT 2011.07.14**
After running for several weeks, the program I had to find small prime factors finished.  The major bug it had involved 
roundoff error, and so reported several
factors which turned out not to be factors, including the two reported above and challenged 
(and correctly so) by Junkie.

I am independently attempting to check the
factorization using the Elliptic Curve Method
of $2^{2557} - 2^{1278} + 1$; that's on its 17th day currently after several restarts of
the computer doing the calculations.

In addition to Charles's answer below, one can look at Hans Riesel's book *Prime Numbers and Computer Methods for Factorization*.  The book has sections on Dickman's Theorem and on the work of Knuth and Trabb-Pardo on how prime factors are distributed according to size.
**END EDIT 2011.07.14**

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.05.06

Comment: So, Gerhard, do you know how to design a bignum system? ... couldn't resist ^_^

Comment: With PFGW:

 2^264097 - 2^132048 + 1 is composite: RES64: [1B3B60AEC3578817] (851.5764s+250.7794s)

Comment: I verified that the other 42 candidates all have small factors (with PFGW).

Comment: Just to make the verification faster: $2^{264097} - 2^{132048} + 1$ has a factor $194528547122653$.

Comment: Thanks Tapio.  Can you confirm that the factor you listed is the smallest such for the candidate?  And thanks for the confirmation on the other candidates.  Gerhard "Thankful For Kindnesses Of Others" Paseman, 2011.05.07

Comment: Ricky, I actually do.  Hans Riesel has the outline of such a package in his classic book on primes and computer factorization, so I would choose an implementation like that as a starting point.  
I welcome further discussion by email if you have a serious interest in how to design a bignum system.  Do you know how?  Gerhard "System Design For Almost Everyone" Paseman, 2011.05.07

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman: The factor was found with ecm, so I do not know if it is the smallest one. Trial factoring up to $194528547122653$ would take much longer than the few minutes I used to the above calculations.

Comment: "my computer suggests that 223381441 divides $2^{2557}−2^{1278}+1$..." except this is not true??
For $2^{121}-2^{60}+1$, the smaller cofactor is $2432582681$, not the $234355951$ you suggest.

Comment: Junkie, perhaps I have a transcription or coding error, more likely the former.  In the link posted above, I have comment in which I make similar claims.  If any one of those is false, then I suspect a coding error.  To make it clear, I claim (and Tapio seems to agree) that of the 47 numbers which are 1 more than a known perfect number, all but 4 are composite, and of those 43, all but one have a prime factor less than 2^32.  The exponents 61 and 1279 I thought I had honestly resolved, and will check again.  Gerhard "Thanks For Checking On Me" Paseman, 2011.05.07

Comment: @Gerhard: I am sorry that I missed your definition of smallness ($<2^{32}$). I am only claiming that all the $43$ numbers have small factors, and I did not look if they are the factors which you got. For example, $2^{2557}−2^{1278}+1$ has a small factor $72353441721527140856665601867$ (which is bigger than $2^{32}$). I can provide you with a complete list of the factors if you want.

Comment: Here is the list of decompositions with small factors http://users.jyu.fi/~tamaraja/temp/factors.txt (I do not claim that those factors are the smallest ones.)

Comment: Thank you Tapio and Junkie.  I now suspect a coding bug and am hunting it down.  I shall update the question with your contributions later today.  Gerhard "Needs More Caution In Action" Paseman, 2011.05.08

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2<sup>32</sup> is fairly small, so the easiest way to determine if the number has a prime factor up to that size is probably just to trial divide.  I just did that in GP:

```
test(p)=my(two=Mod(2,p));two^264097-two^132048+1;
forprime(p=2,1<<32,if(!test(p),return(p)))
```

(actually, I used a customized function rather than forprime() but that makes little difference here) and found that it does not.  The calculation took 10 minutes on a heavily-loaded Phenom II.

Generally to determine the chance of finding a prime factor I would use Mertens' theorem to find the expected number of prime factors in a given range then use negative binomial/Poisson to determine probabilities.

Comment: Did you use the variable p for two different things for any reason other than obfuscation?

Comment: Thank you.  What is your opinion on the result?  Is it suprising to find as many small factors as occurred for a set like this?  (My program still has not tried primes above 2^29.)  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.05.07

Comment: Also, could you explain your test?  The code doesn't look like it is doing trial division.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.05.07

Comment: Gerhard: it's just trial division but with the added complication that p means two different things.

Comment: Maybe someone should edit the code (and add a new variable q) to remove that ambiguity.

Comment: OK.  Is there a reason why p is used (instead of 2) as a base in the exponential expression? Gerhard "Inquiring Minds Want To Know?" Paseman, 2011.05.07